# Using IF, ELSE conditions to iterate through a pandas dataframe, then obtaining and using data from where the set condition was satisfied

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is my dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'First Name': ['George', 'Alex', 'Leo'], 
                   'Surname' : ['Davis', 'Mulan', 'Carlitos'],
                   'Age': [10, 15, 20],
                   'Size' : [30,  40, 50]})
```

Output:

```
First Name   Surname  Age  Size
0     George     Davis   10    30
1       Alex     Mulan   15    40
2        Leo  Carlitos   20    50
```

And here is a function:

```
def myfunc(firstname, surname):
    print(firstname + ' ' + surname)
```

Now, I would like to iterate through the dataframe and check for the following conditions:

- IF df['age'] > than 11 AND df['size'] < 51

If there is a match (row 2 and row 3), I would like to call 'myfunc' and pass in the data from the applicable rows in the dataframe as the attributes of myfunc.

'myfunc()' would be called as:

myfunc(df[First Name], df[Surname])

So in this example the output after running the code would be:

```
'Alex Mulan'
'Leo Carlitos'
```

(The IF, AND condition was true in the second and third row.)

Please explain how could I achieve this goal and provide a working code snippet.

I would prefer a solution where no additional column is created. (If the solution remains practical. Otherwise a new column can be created and added to the dataframe if needed.)

Comment: You can't `myfunc(df[First Name], df[Surname])` because this is not the signature of the callback function of`apply`. The first argument of a callback function is a column (axis=0) or a row (axis=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.loc` to filter your dataframe and apply your function. Use a lambda function as a proxy to call your function with the right signature.

```
def myfunc(firstname, surname):
    return firstname + ' ' + surname

out = df.loc[df['Age'].gt(11) & df['Size'].lt(51), ['First Name', 'Surname']] \
        .apply(lambda x: myfunc(*x), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> out
1      Alex Mulan
2    Leo Carlitos
dtype: object

>>> type(out)
pandas.core.series.Series
```

Comment: At this part of the code:  lambda x: myfunc(*x) what gets passed to myfunc? Am I correct to think that it is two single item tuples like this: ('Alex'), ('Mulan')?

Comment: No this is 2 scalars 'Alex' and 'Mulan'.

Comment: But isn't the *ARGS, (in this context the (*X) in  myfunc(*x) ) supposed to work by creating a Tuple from the elements passed in? I know that if I pass in a tuple that consists of a single string , then pass that tuple as an attribute of  myfunk, then print the type of that attribute I get back a scalar, which in here is a string. I am just really confused as to what's happening. Like in this example here: def myfunk(*args):
    print (type(args))
    
mytuple = (10,12,17,20)
mylist = [84,47,93,55]
mystring = 'Peter'



myfunk(mytuple)
myfunk(mylist)
myfunk(mystring)

Comment: In each case  the type of 'args'  returned as a tuple when Type() is printed? Why is it a scalar in the original example?

Comment: Ok I understand. This is how python unpack arguments, as a tuple to be immutable. Read this: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists

Comment: I finally understand all parts of the code! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

First select the required records using indexing, then concatenate the names:

```
selected = df[(df['Age'] > 11) & (df['Size'] < 51)]
print(selected['First Name'] + " " + selected['Surname'])
```

Edit: to pass each row to a generic function and ensure the right columns are passed, you can write a helper like this:

```
def apply(df, func, kwargs):
    return df[kwargs].rename(columns=kwargs) \
        .apply(lambda row: func(**row), axis=1)

print(apply(df=selected,
    func=myfunc,
    kwargs={"First Name": "firstname", "Surname": "surname"}))
```

There is often a more efficient solution that passes while columns to a function instead of applying it row by row.

Comment: Thanks Stuart, but I need a solution where the actual function is called as the  problem I am trying to resolve is more complex than the example I provided here.

Comment: See edit. You should explain what your actual function does, as there may be better solutions for specific functions

Answer (score 1):

Try with `agg` then

```
df.loc[(df.Age>11) & (df.Size<51),['First Name','Surname']].agg(' '.join,1)
Out[124]: 
1      Alex Mulan
2    Leo Carlitos
dtype: object
```